# When I press the Search button leaving the user input field blank, I get java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, exception, numberformatexception

When I press the Search button leaving the user input field blank, I get the following error page:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
```

Code that throws the error is `int nstudentid = Integer.parseInt(studentid);`

Comment: post the code that is giving you the error.

Comment: line 56:    `int nstudentid = Integer.parseInt(studentid);` I think I need a if statement to say if user input is left blank do something as at the moment i am getting exception report 500. may be somewhere here: `String strQuery = "SELECT studentid,name,surname FROM School where val(studentid) ";

if ( color.equals("blue") )
strQuery += "+ nstudentid ;
else if ( color.equals("green") )`    cheers

Comment: @Brane Can you please edit your question with your code that throws the error? Thanks

Comment: code that throws the error is `int nstudentid = Integer.parseInt(studentid);` thanks

Comment: @PrakashK what do you think about the code? have you seen what might be causing the error here? thanks for helping

Comment: @Brane Try to improve the formatting to help fellow members help you better, for now I have done it.

The answer from @ftom2 is good enough for this error. You can try printing the `studentid` in console right after you get it from request so that you know you are not getting other values, there might be spaces in the `studentid`. So one condition to check can be `!studentid.trim().equals("")` notice the `trim()`

Comment: @Prakashk, I still get the same error as before the code giving by Tom. thanks to both for helping

Comment: @Brane did you print the `String StudentID` on console?

Comment: @PrakashK, yes, I did use the code as following `if(studentid != null && !studentid.equals("")){
    int studentIdNum = Integer.parseInt(studentid);
}
else{
   //no number, deal with it
   System.out.println("Invalid student Id!");
}` OR do you mean anything different? thanks

Comment: @Brane I mean did you write this statement right after u get it from request`System.out.println("student Id=" + studentID + ".")`

Comment: @PrakashK, what do you mean? what are you referring to "u get it from request"? Is it after the following code? : `StudentID = request.getParameter("StudentID")`;. ?? thanks

Comment: @Brane Yes that is what I mean

Comment: @PrakashK , I get in my console the following result `StudentID=.` and   the same error page. Would you know why that result? thanks

Comment: @Brane, I just noticed `int nstudentid = Integer.parseInt(studentid);` the `studentid` is different from `StudentID` string from request, is this a typo in the question or a mistake in your code? Also can you also include your `bourge.jsp` in the question?

Comment: @PrakashK thanks, it's a "typo" in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse a number from a string that is empty, you should add a check:

```
//this means the number is not empty
if(studentid != null && !studentid.equals("")){
    int studentIdNum = Integer.parseInt(studentid);
}
else{
   //no number, deal with it
   throw new Exception("Invalid student Id!");
}
```

Comment: thanks, I thought so too, but it doesn't work. I might be missing something.  @ftom2 `if(studentid != null && !studentid.equals("")){
    //parse the number: how? do i need `out.println("studntid is blank, this is not good!!");`
}
else{
   //no number, deal with it
}` cheers

Comment: If the studentId is empty, you cannot run a query so don't even bother building it.

Comment: well naturally after you get the studentid:  `studentid=request.getParameter("studentid");`